# not sure if my wudu is valid

Tags: salat, wudu

Keeping wudu is a struggle for me because I have a lot of gas which is on and off. I can guess sometimes when it might go away although I am not really 100% sure and if it does go away then i end up reading the prayers really late, for example, i read Dhur when it is almost Asr time. I read that if you cannot control it and it happens a lot then you do one wudu for each prayer. But on another website it says if it goes away then you have to read it during that time. The thing is this is causing me a lot of stress and anxiety because it is a random thing. I am not sure what to do. Should I read the prayers on time even if I am having these problems or delay the prayers to see if the issue goes away and read the prayers then?

Comment: Have you ever wondered why you get a lot of gas?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple and clear:

1. Do one wudu for each prayer.
2. Read the prayers on time.

> حَافِظُوا عَلَى الصَّلَوَاتِ وَالصَّلَاةِ الْوُسْطَىٰ وَقُومُوا
>   لِلَّهِ قَانِتِينَ
>
> "Maintain with care the [obligatory] prayers and [in particular] the
>   middle prayer and stand before Allah , devoutly obedient."
>
> Al-Baqarah (2:238)

.

> إِنَّ الصَّلَاةَ كَانَتْ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ كِتَابًا مَّوْقُوتًا
>
> Indeed, prayer has been decreed upon the believers a decree of
>   specified times.